How to change Root User to Custom User in Dockerfile
I've been attempting to make all users in my Dockerfile to custom user as when running collectstatic in my Django app, I get a error message:
 [Errno 13] Permission denied: 

/code/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/pl.6031b4f16452.js.gz'

I also want to do so for security reasons.
Currently when I run >docker-compose exec web ls -l /code/static I get:
total 16
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 Apr  5 05:42 admin
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 Sep 18 21:21 css
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 Sep 18 21:21 human
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 Sep 18 18:42 img
-rw-r--r-- 1 1234 1234 13091 Sep 18 21:21 staticfiles.json
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 Sep 18 21:21 transcribe

Here is my Dockerfile:
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.11.4-slim-bullseye

# Set environment variables
ENV PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR off
ENV PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV COLUMNS 80

#install Debian and other dependencies that are required to run python apps(eg. git, python-magic).
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --force-yes python3-pip ffmpeg git libmagic-dev libpq-dev gcc \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set working directory for Docker image
WORKDIR /code/

# Install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy project
COPY . .

# Create a custom non-root user
RUN useradd -m example-user

# Grant necessary permissions to write directories and to user 'celery-user'
RUN mkdir -p /code/media /code/static && \
    chown -R example-user:uexample-user /code/media /code/static


# Switch to the non-root user. All this avoids running Celery with root/superuser priviledges which is a security risk
USER example-user


Whenever I rearrange my Dockerfile according to Docker best practice examples and build my image I get a successful build but also several error messages.
Build Error 1:
=> CACHED [celery 5/8] WORKDIR /code/
=> CACHED [celery 6/8] COPY requirements.txt .
=> [celery 7/8] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
=> => # WARNING: The script gunicorn is installed in '/home/example-user/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
=> => # Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
=> => # WARNING: The script django-admin is installed in '/home/example-user/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
=> => # Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
=> => # WARNING: The script celery is installed in '/home/example-user/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
=> => # Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

Build error 2:
=> => transferring context: 49.55kB
=> CACHED [celery 2/8] RUN apt-get update  && apt-get install -y --force-yes python3-pip ffmpeg git libmagic-dev libpq-dev gcc  && r
=> CACHED [celery 3/8] RUN groupadd -g 1234 customgroupexample &&     useradd -m -u 1234 -g customgroupexample example-user
=> [celery 4/8] WORKDIR /code/
=> [celery 5/8] COPY requirements.txt .
=> [celery 6/8] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
=> => # WARNING: The scripts cpack, ctest and cmake are installed in '/home/example-user/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
=> => # Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
=> => # WARNING: The script normalizer is installed in '/home/example-user/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
=> => # Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
=> => # WARNING: The script chardetect is installed in '/home/example-user/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
=> => # Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  Can you [edit] the question to include the error message in plain text?  In normal use I wouldn't expect you to need to chown anything, it's usually good if files are owned by root and world-readable but not writable.  You hint at a Compose setup and I also might check if you're not overwriting the static directory with a named volume.

@DavidMaze Hi I added plaintext error messages.

Frequently with Python in Docker you're installing into the "system" Python, and you need to be root to do that.  Do your installation before you switch USER.

Ok thanks. So I should basically just remove the    chown -R example-user:uexample-user /code/media /code/static line? And no other changes. Wouldn't that still be a security risk?

What security risk are you concerned about?  Having the files readable but not writable (so owned by a different user) is usually better.

@DavidMaze I was concerned that someone could gain root access. I read the Docker docs and they stated that containers should be run as non-root user. I found the problem and replied with the solution.

The /code directory directory does not exist in the dockerfile with the user as the owner so it was created as root. The solution was to chmod the /code directory in the dockerfile, delete the volumes, and run compose up again. Updated Dockerfile:
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.11.4-slim-bullseye

# Set environment variables
ENV PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR off
ENV PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV COLUMNS 80

#install Debian and other dependencies that are required to run python apps(eg. git, python-magic).
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --force-yes python3-pip ffmpeg git libmagic-dev libpq-dev gcc \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set working directory for Docker image
WORKDIR /code/

# Create a non-root user
RUN useradd -m example-user

# Install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy project
COPY . .



# Grant necessary permissions to write directories and to user 'example-user'
RUN mkdir -p /code/media /code/static \
  && chown -R example-user:example-user /code


# Switch to the non-root user. All this avoids running Celery with root/superuser priviledges which is a security risk
USER example-user

Updated compose.yml:
#version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    #command: python /code/manage.py runserver  0.0.0.0:8000
    command: gunicorn mysite.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --reload
    volumes:
      - code_data:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
...
volumes:
  postgres_data:
  code_data:


Your container will keep the ownership and content from the code_data directory; with this volume mount you will not see any changes in your image's /code directory.  I'd recommend deleting this volume entirely.

@DavidMaze When I delete the - code_data:/code and  code_data: and replace with .:/code then run docker compose exec web ls -l /code/static it still shows root owner of all files except staticfile.json.

As I've said in comments on the main question, owned by root is good.  Seeing different results with the volume mount and without is a problem: it means your "it works" case is with a volume only you have, and you haven't fixed the image.

@DavidMaze I'm new to this. What you are saying is completely impenetrable to me. Are you saying that creating files owned by root is ok but running as root is bad? Everything after that I completely do not understand.

Correct, there's pretty much no security risk to having a file owned by root.  (Unless it's executable and has the setuid bit set, but your ordinary Python install won't do this.)

@DavidMaze Ok thank you. How can run the container without root access to prevent a potential attacker from having root access? It is recommended by Docker docs here

The easiest approach is to do all setup and installation steps as root (the linked article mentions for example that if you need to RUN apt-get install you must be root to do it), and only switch to a non-root user at the end of the Dockerfile.  Note that whoever is running the container can always docker run -u root, but also that they can easily docker run a container that takes over the entire host system.

@DavidMaze Ok. That's what I've been doing. I deleted everything(images, builds, volumes, cache) and rebuilt again then ran docker-compose exec web ls -l /code and docker-compose exec web ls -l /code/static. The result is root as owner for everything except static files. The original issue I had (running collectstatic) still fails because PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/code/static/admin/js/calendar.js.gz' and similar errors due to not having permission.
